# Beginnings of VC++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have done small project in c++, the IDE I am using is Visual Studio 2010. The program right now runs through command prompt. I wish to shift to VC++ so that I am able have buttons and dialogue boxes, in order to make an interaction with the user in a more human way. What I seek for are small things to start with. Can anyone provide guidelines so that it would become easier to start things with.

Comment: There are tons of various libraries for this. Decide the complexity that you need and requirements.

Comment: "visual c++" has nothing to do with a user interface, it's just the name of the compiler (or IDE, depending on what source one reads); so you don't shift to it, you are using it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is create a Choose MFC->Dialog based application which will help you to start with creating dialog box and controls like buttons, radio buttons and checkboxes. Moreover i would suggest you to read [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1572316950) book.

Answer (score 3):

What you call **VC++** is actually **Visual C++**, as in the **C++** "component" of the **Visual Studio** IDE. So you are already using **VC++**, but (blame Microsoft) even though it's called visual, it has no visual components.

If you want to create a user interface for your program you need to use an extra library. There are quite some good ones you can choose from:

1) [QT](http://qt.nokia.com/products/)

2) [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/)

3) [SO discussion on the topic of GUI libraries for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115045/good-c-gui-library-for-windows)